# How to use jooq codegen to automatically add custom fields to build pojos?

Tags: java, sql, jooq, codegen

I use jooq codegen to generate entity classes like this :

```java
public class TCoactivitiesPinan extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2007524284;
private Integer   id;
private String    openid;
private String    tel;
private Timestamp createdtime;
...}
```

but,I want it to automatically determine that if it's a time type, it automatically adds two fields. like this

```java
public class TCoactivitiesPinan extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2007524284;
private Integer   id;
private String    openid;
private String    tel;
private Timestamp createdtime;
private String createdtime_start; //  创建时间_开始时间
private String createdtime_end; //  创建时间_结束时间
private Integer   checkstate;
...
}
```

Is there any way to solve it? ths.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own code generator and extend the POJO's "custom code section" as documented here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-custom-code

Essentially, just write a class like this:

```java
public class MyGenerator extends JavaGenerator {

    @Override
    protected void generatePojoClassFooter(TableDefinition table, JavaWriter out) {
        for (ColumnDefinition column : table.getColumns()) {
            if (column.getType().getType().equals("TIMESTAMP")) {
                out.tab(1).println("private String %s_start; //  创建时间_开始时间", 
                    getStrategy().getJavaMemberName(column, Mode.POJO));
                out.tab(1).println("private String %s_end; //  创建时间_结束时间", 
                    getStrategy().getJavaMemberName(column, Mode.POJO));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then, configure it as follows:

```xml
<configuration>
    ...
    <generator>
        <name>com.example.MyGenerator</name>
        ...
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Of course, the above solution will only generate the desired members, it will not generate any logic to populate those members when you use the generated POJO type.

Comment: When I built it your way, the build failed. The error is as follows :[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.10.3:generate (default-cli) on project parkingmanage: Error running jOOQ code generation tool: com.exmp.MyGenerator -> [Help 1]       -------------------- and pom like this:<generator><name>com.exmp.MyGenerator</name><database>...</database><generate></generate><strategy>...</strategy><target>...</target></generator>

Comment: @hjk9317: I'm sure it works this way, but perhaps you have a classpath problem? Would you mind creating a new question with more details?